# Potential silly JS question from a Newbie (html and API with axios)

Tags: javascript, axios, get

I'm quite new with JS, not so much with programming in general (C++, Python...)
The goal I have is quite basic but I can't find a simple and elegant solution to my problem.
I'd like to have a single html page with a header + a table.
This table should display json data I get to from an existing 3p API.

What I need my code to do

1. Execute on loading the html page (not using a buton) > I use <script...>
2. The code should start by getting the api data (I use Axios)
3. Run a formatting function (to change multi-layer json to an array of key: values objects)
4. Update the display page (using vue JS)

Where I'm at now
Code start on loading > OK
Code gets the data using axios  > OK (almost)
run formating function > NOT OK since this function start before the end of the axios get function is finished

The way i'd like to structure my code : (pseudo code)
index.js

```
const formattedDataArray = [];
const unformattedData;

function getAPIData() {
   use axios to get data;
   return unformattedData;}

function formatData() {
   transform unformatedData;}

function updateHTMLWithData() {
   update html using viewJS;}

/*start execution here*/
unformattedData = getAPIData();
formatedData = formatData();
updateHTMLwithData();
```

The getAPIData function works
The transformData fucntion works
BUT...
because of the time it takes to get the data from the server, the `transformData()` function is executed before the end of the `getAPIData()` function (I checked with a lot of `console.log()`)

Here is my code.
Could you please point me in the right direction as if you were talking to a 3year old ? ;)
Thanks

```
let jsonData = [];
const formattedData = [];

async function getAPIData() {
  console.log('Start getAPIData');
  // fetch data from a url endpoint
  const data = await axios.get('https://myurl.domain/api', {
    headers: {
      crossDomain: true,
      'app-id'    : 'won't tell',
      'app-secret': 'won't tell either'
      }
    });
    console.log(data.data);
    console.log('End getAPIData');
  return data;
}

function formatData() {
   console.log('Sart formatData');
   /* do relevant stuff here with jsonData to formattedData*/
   console.log('End formatData');
}

/*main executing here*/
  console.log('Start Main Code');
  jsonData = getAPIData();
  console.log('After getAPIDate'); 
  formatData();
  console.log(formattedData);
  console.log('Fin du script');
```

Comment: have you heard of promise ?

Comment: I've read it is needed for async functions, but that's almost all I know about it.

Comment: you can use it with or without async. try write your code with promise